# Некорректная работа парсера

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Код на Python 3:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BeautifulSoup
import json

site = 'http://www.problems.ru/view_problem_details_new.php?id='
index = 88018
site = site + str(index)
response = requests.get(site)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
box = soup.find("div", {"class":"componentboxcontents"})
print(box.findAll('p'))
```

По-идее, он должен отыскивать все теги `p` в определенном `div`'e, однако теги  `p` пустые. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: *все теги 'p' (изза скобок криво отобразилось)

Answer (score 4):

Проверил html, которое пришло, и которое в браузере – немного отличаются – в браузере в тегах `<p>` содержится текст, но в скрипте приходят пустые `<p>`, после которых уже содержится текст, может их сервер проверяет на ботов, а может есть небольшой `javascript`, который текст вставляет в `<p>`.

Алгоритм:

Находим `<p>` и после них берем текст, удаляя пробелы, символы перехода, и т.п. вокруг текста. У меня установлен модуль `lxml` из-за чего `BeautifulSoup` немного ругается, поэтому и конструктор принимает такой параметр, удалите, если мешается.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rs = requests.get('http://www.problems.ru/view_problem_details_new.php?id=88018')

html = BeautifulSoup(rs.content.decode('KOI8-R'), 'lxml')
box = html.find(attrs={"class": "componentboxcontents"})

for i, p in enumerate(box.findAll('p'), 1):
    print(i, p.nextSibling.strip())
    print()
```

Результат:

```
1 На столе
лежат в ряд пять монет: средняя  — вверх орлом, а остальные  — вверх
решкой. Разрешается одновременно
перевернуть три рядом лежащие монеты. Можно ли при помощи нескольких
таких переворачиваний все пять монет положить вверх орлом?

2 Попробуйте перевернуть первые три монеты.

3 Это действительно можно сделать, причём довольно быстро.
Перевернём первые три монеты. Тогда первые две монеты будут лежать вверх
орлом, а последние три  — вверх решкой. Теперь переворачиваем последние
три монеты, и все пять монет лежат вверх орлом.

4 Да: первым ходом перевернём первые 3 монеты,
вторым  — последние 3.
```

Comment: Как раз такая же ситуация в моем вопросе)