# Текст, при парсинге, за пределами тега p

Tags: html, python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Спарсил ссылки типа:

```
reference = "*"
```

Перехожу по ним с помощью requests:

```
r = get(reference)
```

Получаю ответ валидного вида. Потом паршу контент на предмет `div`'а с классом `componentboxcontents` и записываю в файл:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
box = soup.find("div", {"class":"componentboxcontents"})
file2.write(str(box))
```

Но в файле я вижу следующую картину:

```
<p>
</p>
Ключ показывает, какие именно стрелки отходят из того места, где стоит буква, которую мы
должны выбрать. В результате прочитывается слово КОМПЬЮТЕР.
```

Текст стоит за пределами тега `p` и не поддаётся дальнейшему парсингу(При том, так во всех тегах `p`), хотя должен выглядить примерно так:

```
<p>
  Ключ показывает, какие именно стрелки отходят из того места, где стоит буква, которую мы
  должны выбрать. В результате прочитывается слово КОМПЬЮТЕР.
</p>
```

Как пофиксить?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510553 - это ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Nofate, нет, но полагаю, что автор этого вопроса - мой знакомый.